# How to use free with a struct that has pointers?

Tags: c

i'm trying to use free to the pointers inside of the struct, then i use free with the struct, it's seems correct but it i got this error:  free(): invalid next size (fast); the error msg is greater but i think this is enough to know that is about an error memory.

Here is my code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>

    typedef struct{
        char *nome;
        char *endereco;
        char *matricula;
    }Estudante;

    char *strAlloc( int n ){
        return ( char *) malloc( n * sizeof( char * ));
    }

    int lineReader( char **str ){

        char c;
        int length = 10, strI = 0;

        getchar();

        *str = strAlloc( length );
        while ( 1 ){

            c = getchar();

            if ( strI+1 == length ){

                length += 10;

                *str = ( char * ) realloc( *str, length * sizeof( char *));

                if( *str == NULL){
                    printf("Faltou memoria\n");
                    return 0;
                }
            }
            if ( c == '\n' ) break;

            (*str)[ strI++ ] = c;
        }

        return strI;
    }

    int main(){



        Estudante *alunos;
        int n, length, i, j;
        char *str;
        char c;

        printf("Digite a quantidade de alunos:\n");
        scanf(" %d", &n);

        alunos = ( Estudante * ) malloc( n * sizeof( Estudante * ));

        for (i = 0; i < n; ++i){

            printf("Digite o nome do aluno %d:\n", i+1);

            length = lineReader ( &str );

            alunos[ i ].nome = strAlloc( length );
            strcpy( alunos[ i ].nome, str );

            printf("Digite o endereço do aluno:\n");

            length = lineReader ( &str );
            alunos[ i ].endereco = strAlloc( length );
            strcpy( alunos[ i ].endereco, str );

            printf("Digite a matricula do aluno:\n");

            length = lineReader ( &str );
            alunos[ i ].matricula = strAlloc( length );
            strcpy( alunos[ i ].matricula, str );

            printf("\n");
        }

        free( str );

        for (i = 0; i < n; ++i){

            printf("Dados do aluno %d\n", i+1);
            printf("Nome: %s\n", alunos[ i ].nome );
            printf("Endereço: %s\n", alunos[ i ].endereco );
            printf("matricula: %s\n\n", alunos[ i ].matricula );

            free( alunos[ i ].nome );
            free( alunos[ i ].endereco );
            free( alunos[ i ].matricula );
        }

        free( alunos );
        alunos = NULL;

        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The following line is wrong:

```
alunos = ( Estudante * ) malloc( n * sizeof( Estudante * ));
```

You need to allocate space for n `struct Estudante` rather than  space for n pointers.  You can avoid this error by using the idiom:

```
alunos = malloc( n * sizeof *alunos );
```

Also note that, while in C++ it is necessary to cast the return value of `malloc`, it is neither necessary nor desirable to do so in C.  (In the late 80's, it was good practice to supply the cast.  Those days are gone.)

Comment: Thanks it works! could you explain-me why i need to do, sizeof * alunos instead of sizeof( Estudante * ) ??

Comment: `sizeof *alunos` is the same as `sizeof Estudante` which is the size of 3 pointers to char.  `sizeof Estudante *` is the size of 1  pointer to Estudante.  Object pointers to different objects are the same size, so you are underallocating by a factor of 3.

Answer (score 0):

You have the right form for freeing the struct, something else must have corrupted the heap earlier.

It looks like your strings aren't null terminated
in lineReader

```
if ( c == '\n' ) break;
```

should be

```
if ( c == '\n' ) {
(*str)[strI] = '\0'; //Not incrementing strI because the null character doesn't count towards the string size
break;
}
```

Because it's not null terminated the string functions like strcpy might be grabbing more than it's supposed to. Consider using strncpy if it's available.

Also, free(str) should be inside this for loop right? lineReader() will just keep allocing a new string every time without freeing the old one.

```
for (i = 0; i < n; ++i){

        printf("Digite o nome do aluno %d:\n", i+1);

        length = lineReader ( &str );

        alunos[ i ].nome = strAlloc( length );
        strcpy( alunos[ i ].nome, str );

        printf("Digite o endereço do aluno:\n");

        length = lineReader ( &str );
        alunos[ i ].endereco = strAlloc( length );
        strcpy( alunos[ i ].endereco, str );

        printf("Digite a matricula do aluno:\n");

        length = lineReader ( &str );
        alunos[ i ].matricula = strAlloc( length );
        strcpy( alunos[ i ].matricula, str );

        printf("\n");
    }

    free( str );
```

Comment: Hi, i did this before, but the program just works nice when i remove the line free( aluno );

Comment: @mathe: the fact that you don't get a crash doesn't mean that you did things correctly. You get a crash when calling `free` because it performs some checks on the heap in order to deallocate the memory; if `free` crashes, it means that you messed up the heap, and removing the call to `free` is just hiding your head under the sand.

Comment: Sure, when i say that the program works nice it means that i don't get a crash, but the problem was solved, i did what William Pursell said.